# Form validation is not working properly in Metronic

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, metronic

I'm using metronic framework for my application. This metronic form allows white-spaces as valid with (tick) mark even if don't enter any character.

Until user enter the value field should be invalid.

Here sample link how it works
http://keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/admin_4/form_validation.html

Please go to "VALIDATION USING ICONS" form and type 3 or more spaces in nae field and then you can see tick mark icon for valid which is not valid truly.

Can you suggest how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can find this validation in file `\assets\pages\scripts\form-validation.js`.

First, add an additional method `noSpace` to validate whitespaces. Then you can modify the method which handles validation for `#form_sample_2` which is `handleValidation2`. You just need to enter `noSpace: true` in `rules` for `name`

The entire code is given below:

```
// validation using icons

// Additional method to validate whitespaces
jQuery.validator.addMethod("noSpace", function(value, element) { 
  return value == '' || value.trim().length != 0; 
}, "No space please and don't leave it empty");

var handleValidation2 = function() {
    // for more info visit the official plugin documentation: 
    // http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

    var form2 = $('#form_sample_2');
    var error2 = $('.alert-danger', form2);
    var success2 = $('.alert-success', form2);

    form2.validate({
        errorElement: 'span', //default input error message container
        errorClass: 'help-block help-block-error', // default input error message class
        focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input
        ignore: "",  // validate all fields including form hidden input
        rules: {
            name: {
                minlength: 2,
                required: true,
                noSpace: true
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            url: {
                required: true,
                url: true
            },
            number: {
                required: true,
                number: true
            },
            digits: {
                required: true,
                digits: true
            },
            creditcard: {
                required: true,
                creditcard: true
            },
        },

        invalidHandler: function (event, validator) { //display error alert on form submit              
            success2.hide();
            error2.show();
            App.scrollTo(error2, -200);
        },

        errorPlacement: function (error, element) { // render error placement for each input type
            var icon = $(element).parent('.input-icon').children('i');
            icon.removeClass('fa-check').addClass("fa-warning");  
            icon.attr("data-original-title", error.text()).tooltip({'container': 'body'});
        },

        highlight: function (element) { // hightlight error inputs
            $(element)
                .closest('.form-group').removeClass("has-success").addClass('has-error'); // set error class to the control group   
        },

        unhighlight: function (element) { // revert the change done by hightlight

        },

        success: function (label, element) {
            var icon = $(element).parent('.input-icon').children('i');
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success'); // set success class to the control group
            icon.removeClass("fa-warning").addClass("fa-check");
        },

        submitHandler: function (form) {
            success2.show();
            error2.hide();
            form[0].submit(); // submit the form
        }
    });
}
```

Once this is done, minify the `form-validation.js` file and replace the existing `form-validation.min.js` file.